# Flutter setState() function is not working: W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection error

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, setstate

i am making a body-mass index application and i need to get user input to calculate the bmi formula. So i use setState() function to update height and weight according to the information i get from user, but they are not updated. Can you please help?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'calculation.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'BMI';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[900],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum SingingCharacter { lafayette, jefferson }

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  SingingCharacter _character = SingingCharacter.lafayette;
  double height=1;
  double weight=1;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

      child:Scrollbar(

      child:SingleChildScrollView(
        child:Card(
          color: Colors.amber[50],
      child:Column(

        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 10, 10),
            child: Text("Sex:",
            style:TextStyle(fontSize: 24, letterSpacing: 1.0)),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Female',
                style:TextStyle(fontSize: 18, letterSpacing: 1.0)
            ),
            leading: Radio(
              activeColor: Colors.orange,
              value: SingingCharacter.lafayette,
              groupValue: _character,
              onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                setState(() {
                  _character = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Male',
                style:TextStyle(fontSize: 18, letterSpacing: 1.0,)
            ),
            leading: Radio(
              activeColor: Colors.orange,
              value: SingingCharacter.jefferson,
              groupValue: _character,
              onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                setState(() {
                  _character = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),

              Text("Your height:",
              style:TextStyle(fontSize: 24, letterSpacing: 1.0)
              ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 50, 10),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Your height(cm)"),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                  ], // Only numbers can be entered
                  onSubmitted: (input1){
                    if(input1 as double>0){
                    setState(() => height=input1 as double);
                    print(input1);
               //   }
                  },
                ),
          ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text("Your weight:",
              style:TextStyle(fontSize: 24, letterSpacing: 1.0)
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
                Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 50, 10),
                  child:  new TextField(
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Your weight(kg)"),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ], // Only numbers can be entered
                    onSubmitted: (input2){
                      if (input2 as double>0){
           //             print(weight);
                     setState(() {
                       return weight=input2 as double;
                     });

                    }
                    },
                  ),),
    SizedBox(height: 10,),
    RaisedButton(
      padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5),
    onPressed: (){
        return Calculation(height, weight);
    },
    color: Colors.amber[900],
    child:Text(
    'Calculate',
    style:TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 30,
      letterSpacing: 2.0,
    ),
    ),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 20,),
    Text('Results: $height,$weight'),

    ],
      ),
        ),
    ),
      ),
    );
    }

  }
```

And this is the Calculation function:

```
import 'dart:math';


void Calculation(height,weight){
    double value=pow(height,2)/weight;
    print(value);
   // return value.toString();
}

void Results(value){
  if(value<18.5){
    print("kilonuz ideal kilonuzdan az.");
  }
  if(value>25){
     if(value>30){
         print("kilonuz ideal kilonuzun çok üstünde, sağlığınız risk altında.");
     }
     else{
         print("kilonuz ideal kilonuzdan fazla.");
     }
  }
  else{
      print("ideal kilonuzdasınız.");
  }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
I/flutter ( 4965): 1.0
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4965): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "not working". What do you do? What happens when you do it? what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: "x as double" will not convert a text of digits into a double. `double.parse(x)` will do that.

Comment: @nvoigt thank you so much for the answer. by saying "not working", i meant i couldn't get any printed value even the function runs, but double.parse(x) really worked ^-^ i am new in this language.